# Angular 8 - Architecture/Routing Best Practice (advice)

Tags: angular, angular-routing, directory-structure

I am new to angular and a bit confused with the architecture recommendations.
To avoid a broad question I will form it in a A or B kind of style, and a how to achieve that. The question is regards to lazy loading, and optimization

So I have a basic SPA, with a login page, a 404, and a few pages you can view only if you are logged in (=feature pages).

**Requirement:**
the feature pages have a navbar, sidebar and footer, whereas the login and 404 pages do not.

**approach A:**

- a shell component with a module and a routing module

  - the module will import all feature pages with their routing
- each feature page will have its routing, loaded as a child from the shell component

Tree:

```
app/
    login/
          login-component
          login-routing.module.ts
          login.module.ts
    pageNotFound/ (similar to login)
    shell/
          page1/
                page1-component1
                page1-component2
                page1-routing.module.ts
                page1.module.ts
          page2/ (similar to 1 etc)
          shell-routing.module.ts
          shell.module.ts
```

**approach B:**

this is much simpler, instead of each feature page having its own routing module, shell-routing module will have all routes

**shell-routing.module.ts:**

`const shellRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ShellComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'page1Component1', component: page1-component1},
      { path: 'page1Component2', component: page1-component2},
      ...
    ],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
]`

**approach C:**
open to suggestions!

from my research **approach A** seems to be the best approach
my issue with **approach A**, which led to approach B:

suppose the side bar navigation:

`Dashboard
Profile
Dropdown-group ->
    page1
    page2
About Us`

if I am on the **dashboard page**, and select **page1**, the dropdown closes.
if I am on the **page1**, and select **page2**, the dropdown works as expected.

this is solved with **approach B**, but I guess my question is how/if I can manage this with **approach A**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my approach to a similar problem, where I had an auth page and feature pages.

#### app.module.ts

```js
/* ... */
imports: [
 /* ... */
 AuthModule, // Contains `/auth` route
 ShellModule,
]
/* ... */
```

#### shell-routing.module.ts

```js
 path: '',
    component: ShellComponent,
    canLoad: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'feat1',
        loadChildren: () => import('../feat1/feat1.module').then(m => m.Feat1Module),
      },
      {
        path: 'feat2',
        loadChildren: () => import('../feat2/feat2.module').then(m => m.Feat2Module),
      },
    /* ... */
    ]
```

#### shell.component.html

```html
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>

<router-outlet>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

In my situation, after login is successful, I'd redirect to one of the pages mentioned above.

Also, it is **important** that you use a `canLoad` guard for lazy-loaded modules, this will prevent them from actually being loaded if the navigation to them is not allowed. If you were to use `canActivate`, even though the navigation would fail, the module would be loaded anyway.

---

#### What if `feat1` has sub feature components, how should its routing module be?

Here's how I'd define it:

```js
// feat1-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Feat1,
    children: [
     {
      path: ':id',
      component: Feat1SingleComponent,
     },
  // It can also have lazy-loaded modules!
     {
      path: 'lazy',
      loadChildren: () => import('../lazy/lazy.module').then(m => 
      m.LazyModule)
     },
   ]
  },
];
```

```html
<!-- feat1.component.html -->

<!-- ... -->

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: thanks for the canLoad tip! ill check your answer and try to implement it and let you know :)

Comment: clarification: the feat1 would not have a router-module?

Comment: `feat1` would have a router-module because it is a **lazy-loaded** module.  Any lazy-loaded module must have routes defined, even if it is something like `{ path: '', component: MyAwesomeComponent}`.

Comment: works like a charm! exactly what i wanted with apparoach A, my only issue, if feat1 has sub feature components, how should its routing module be? i found/tried several ways but none feels "correct", and more impotantly, how can the feat1 router module prevent from navigating to that link?

Comment: @Alexandros I have updated my answer. Hope it is what you meant :)

Comment: so /feat1/lazy would end up loading/showing lazy component right? if you just go at /lazy, wouldnt that also load/show the lazy component? just outside of the "shell" component?

Comment: No, if you go to `/lazy` , it should not load the lazy module. That's because it is defined as a child route(so it belongs to `feat1`), which also means that when you add the `path` in the `children array` of `feat1`, it would first prepend the path of the parent, then use what is defined in the children array(so it becomes `/feat1/lazy`). 
Basically, `/lazy` does not exist, but `/feat1/lazy` does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198368/discussion-between-alexandros-and-andrei-gtej).

Comment: I do not know if it is still a good practice ... It works for small apps. If the `feat2` needs a specific component of the `feat1`, so it needs to import the module of the `feat1` so its routing module. The routes of the two modules gets "merged" and conflicts can occur. So a module with defined routes can not export any component without disturbing the routing system after its importation in another module (which defined its routes) ...

Comment: @cactuschibre I think a way to solve this is to create a shared module(which differs from the well-known shared module which contains dumb components) and add that common component there.